# Older frameworks in Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I got the latest version of Xcode (3.2) When I open an older project in Xcode all the frameworks appear in red. When I replace them with the current frameworks i get a ton of errors in my code. I want to run the 2.2.1 simulator but it isn't in the list of active SDK's.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the iPhone OS SDK installer package don't include all older SDKs, as people were complaining about the growing size of the installers.

The 2.2.1 Simulator doesn't run on Snow Leopard.  So you're out of luck there entirely.

Set your Base SDK to an SDK you do have (like 3.0), and set your iPhone Deployment Target to 2.2.1, and you'll be able to test on a 2.2.1 device, though still not in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

And to address the annoying/alarming red color (in Xcode 3.2.4 Prelease, developing for iOS4.1),

[1] select a red (mis-referenced) framework in the "Groups & Files" pane
[2] get its "Info" (command-I, or click the blue circle with the white italic "i")
[3] of the three tabs, "General", "Targets", and "Comments", choose "General"
[4] Use the "Path Type:" pop-up: 
    change from "Relative to Current SDK" to "Absolute Path"
[5] Click the "Choose..." button to select a path like:

"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework"

[6] Notice:
    the "Path Type:" pop-up returns to "Relative to Current SDK" automatically; and
    the framework's annoying/alarming red color is replaced by the normal/copacetic black.

No doubt, some later upgrade of Xcode will manage all this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Base SDK for All Configurations" to the prelease sdk (in this case, iOS Device 4.1) fixed my missing frameworks problem.